# What precisely do I/my company need to do "make available/publish" source code changes and satisfy GPL/LGPL

Tags: gpl, lgpl

This seems like a basic question, but I have not found a definitive source.

I need to modify the source for an LGPL application for my employer to plug a security hole. Longer term we will upgrade to a later version of this application, but for now, this is the quickest solution.

(specifically: I will change a 2005-era version fork of Apache Tomcat'--jboss-web 2.0.1--to add allow "httpOnly" and 'secure' JSESSIONID cookie).

**The question**

What exactly must I/my company do to "make available" or "publish" the source code?

Must it be accessible from the company's own website or github repository?  Or can I have it on my own private github account and simply have the company link to it?

thanks

Comment: You may wish to avoid having the company link to your private account.  What happens if you leave or are fired?

Comment: ok you are modifying the source but are you distributing the modified binary to anyone or just using it internally? if you don't distribute the binary you do not need to publish the source anyway

Answer (score 1):

> #### Option (a): Source Alongside Binary
>
> GPLv2 § 3(a) and v3 § 6(a) embody the easiest option for providing
> source code: including Corresponding Source with every binary
> distribution. While other options appear initially less onerous, this
> option invariably minimizes potential compliance problems, because
> when you distribute Corresponding Source with the binary, your GPL
> obligations are satisfied at the time of distribution.
>
> #### Option (b): The Offer
>
> Many distributors prefer to ship only an offer for source with the
> binary distribution, rather than the complete source package. This
> option has value when the cost of source distribution is a true
> per-unit cost. For example, this option might be a good choice for
> embedded products with permanent storage too small to fit the source,
> and which are not otherwise shipped with a CD but are shipped with a
> manual or other printed material.
>
> However, this option increases the duration of your obligations
> dramatically. An offer for source must be good for three full years
> from your last binary distribution (under GPLv2), or your last binary
> or spare part distribution (under GPLv3). Your source code request and
> provisioning system must be designed to last much longer than your
> product life cycle.
>
> In addition, if you are required to comply with the terms of GPLv2,
> you cannot use a network service to provide the source code. For
> GPLv2, the source code offer is fulfilled only with physical media.
> This usually means that you must continue to produce an up-to-date
> “source code CD” for years after the product’s end-of-life.
>
> Under GPLv2, it is acceptable and advisable for your offer for source
> code to include an Internet link for downloadable source in addition
> to offering source on a physical medium. This practice enables those
> with fast network connections to get the source more quickly, and
> typically decreases the number of physical media fulfillment requests.
> (GPLv3 § 6(b) permits provision of source with a public
> network-accessible distribution only and no physical media.

http://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2008/compliance-guide.html

Comment: It seems not everyone agrees with that interpretation of GPLv2 § 3(b). For example, [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/license.html) says that the distribution "is often a URL", implying this is legitimate and common. Is the correctness of network distribution a misconception? On what grounds would one think that it is incorrect? I can't see from the text of the GPLv2 why network distribution would not be considered physically performing distribution of machine-readable source code on a customarily-used medium. I thought it was *the* customary medium for source distribution.

Comment: Never mind, I see now that [the FSF's GPLv2 FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.en.html#TOCSourceAndBinaryOnDifferentSites) seems to answer this, that posting the source on a site with the URL available was intended to be allowed as a way to fulfill § 3 **(a)**, not **(b)**.